# Create a score column in pandas whose value depends on the percentile of another column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have the following dataframe:

```
User_ID Game_ID votes
1         11    1040
1         11    nan
1         22    1101
1         11    540
1         33    nan
2         33    nan
2         33    290
2         33    nan
```

Based on the percentile of the values in the column `votes`, a new column needs to be created, per the following rules:

> If the “votes” value is >= 75th percentile assign a score of 2
>
> If >=25th percentile assign a score of 1
>
> If <25th percentile assign a score of 0.

Comment: You should add the `pandas` tag to reach more people

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the percentiles by calling describe and use list comprehension:

```
percentiles = df.votes.describe()
df['scores'] = [2 if x >= percentiles['75%'] else (0 if x < percentiles['25%'] else 1) for x in df.votes]
```

Comment: How so if I may ask?

Comment: Well, `describe` is (to me, at least), a function for generating a *human-readable* text summary of a dataset, and not something I would use to calculate quantiles for use (as opposed to for viewing). It just happens to be in the form of a `Series`, which is why this works. It's creative, though. +1

Answer (score 2):

Use `pd.qcut`:

```
df['score'] = pd.qcut(df['votes'].astype(float), [0, 0.25, 0.75, 1.0]).cat.codes
print(df)
```

Output (`nan` corresponds to `-1`):

```
0    1
1   -1
2    2
3    1
4   -1
5   -1
6    0
7   -1
dtype: int8
```